# How can i create multiple tables under single/multiple datasets using Terraform - GCP BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform

Currently, I was able to create single table under each dataset, Below is the code i have created;

```
main.tf
#############################################################
# BIGQUERY DATASET
#############################################################

resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "bq_dataset" {
  for_each      = var.bq_tables_schema
  dataset_id    = each.value["dataset_id"]
  friendly_name = each.value["friendly_name"]

}

#############################################################
# BIGQUERY TABLE
#############################################################

resource "google_bigquery_table" "tables" {
      for_each   = var.bq_tables_schema

      dataset_id = each.value["dataset_id"]
      table_id   = each.value["table_id"]

      
      schema = each.value["schema"]


      depends_on = [google_bigquery_dataset.bq_dataset]
}
```

here is the Terraform version i was using;

```
version.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
      version     = "~> 3.63.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
}
```

Below is the variables file;

```
variable.tf
     bq_tables_schema     = {
            "dataset1" = {
                "dataset_id"    = "bq_dataset_sentinel_test_1",
                "friendly_name" = "bq_dataset_sentinel_test_1",
                "table_id" = "bq_table_1",
                "schema"   = <<EOF
             [
                                {
                                  "name": "scan_time1",
                                  "type": "STRING",
                                  "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                  "description": "scan time1"
                                },
                                {
                                  "name": "scan_duration1",
                                  "type": "STRING",
                                  "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                  "description": "scan duration1"
                                },
                                {
                                  "name": "scm_url",
                                  "type": "STRING",
                                  "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                  "description": "scm url"
                                }
                              ]
                            EOF
            },
            "dataset2" = {
                "dataset_id"    = "bq_dataset_sentinel_test_2",
                "friendly_name" = "bq_dataset_sentinel_test_2",
                "table_id"  = "bq_table_11",
                "schema"    = <<EOF
             [
                                {
                                  "name": "scan_time11",
                                  "type": "STRING",
                                  "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                  "description": "scan time11"
                                },
                                {
                                  "name": "scan_duration11",
                                  "type": "STRING",
                                  "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                  "description": "scan duration11"
                                }
                              ]
                          EOF
                }

            }
```

Everything looks good, but now im trying to create multiple tables under each dataset, how can i do that?

Here is the variable; i was trying to create multiple tables under each/multiple dataset :
How do i flatten this variable?

```
     bq_tables_schema     = {
            "dataset1" = {
                "dataset_id"    = "bq_dataset_sentinel_test_1",
                "friendly_name" = "bq_dataset_sentinel_test_1",
                "table_schema" = {
                    "table_1" = {
                        "table_id" = "bq_table_1",
                        "schema"   = <<EOF
                                     [
                                      {
                                        "name": "scan_time1",
                                        "type": "STRING",
                                        "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                        "description": "scan time1"
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "name": "scan_duration1",
                                        "type": "STRING",
                                        "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                        "description": "scan duration1"
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "name": "scm_url",
                                        "type": "STRING",
                                        "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                        "description": "scm url"
                                      }
                                    ]
                                EOF
                            },
                    "table_2" =     {
                        "table_id" = "bq_table_2",
                        "schema"   = <<EOF
                                     [
                                      {
                                        "name": "scan_time2",
                                        "type": "STRING",
                                        "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                        "description": "scan time2"
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "name": "scan_duration2",
                                        "type": "STRING",
                                        "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                        "description": "scan duration2"
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "name": "scm_url2",
                                        "type": "STRING",
                                        "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                        "description": "scm url2"
                                      }
                                    ]
                                EOF
                      }
                }
            },
            "dataset2" = {
                "dataset_id"    = "bq_dataset_sentinel_test_2",
                "friendly_name" = "bq_dataset_sentinel_test_2",
                "table_schema" = {
                    "table_1" = {
                        "table_id"  = "bq_table_11",
                        "schema"    = <<EOF
                                      [
                                        {
                                          "name": "scan_time11",
                                          "type": "STRING",
                                          "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                          "description": "scan time11"
                                        },
                                        {
                                          "name": "scan_duration11",
                                          "type": "STRING",
                                          "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                          "description": "scan duration11"
                                        }
                                      ]
                                  EOF
                        },
                    "table_2" =     {
                        "table_id"  = "bq_table_22",
                        "schema"    = <<EOF
                                   [
                                    {
                                      "name": "scan_time22",
                                      "type": "STRING",
                                      "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                      "description": "scan time22"
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "name": "scan_duration22",
                                      "type": "STRING",
                                      "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                      "description": "scan duration22"
                                    }
                                  ]
                              EOF
                    }
                }
            }
          }
```

Could someone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I just figure-out the solution, to create multiple datasets with multiple tables;

i have added locals.tf to flattent eh variable,

```
local.tf

locals {
  dataset_tables = flatten([
    for dataset, dataset_info  in var.bq_tables_schema : [
      for table, table_data  in dataset_info.table_schema : {
        dataset_id    = dataset_info.dataset_id
        friendly_name = dataset_info.friendly_name
        table_id      = table_data.table_id
        schema        = table_data.schema
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

here is the main.tf;

```
main.tf


#############################################################
# BIGQUERY DATASET
#############################################################

resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "bq_dataset" {
  for_each      = var.bq_tables_schema
  dataset_id    = each.value["dataset_id"]
  friendly_name = each.value["friendly_name"]

}

#############################################################
# BIGQUERY TABLE
#############################################################

resource "google_bigquery_table" "tables" {
      for_each = {
                for dt in local.dataset_tables : "${dt.dataset_id}-${dt.table_id}" => dt
        }

      dataset_id = each.value.dataset_id
      table_id   = each.value.table_id

      
      schema = each.value.schema


      depends_on = [google_bigquery_dataset.bq_dataset]
}
```

Here is the variables.tf file

```
     bq_tables_schema     = {
            "dataset1" = {
                "dataset_id"    = "bq_dataset_sentinel_test_1",
                "friendly_name" = "bq_dataset_sentinel_test_1",
                "table_schema" = {
                    "table_1" = {
                        "table_id" = "bq_table_1",
                        "schema"   = <<EOF
                                     [
                                      {
                                        "name": "scan_time1",
                                        "type": "STRING",
                                        "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                        "description": "scan time1"
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "name": "scan_duration1",
                                        "type": "STRING",
                                        "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                        "description": "scan duration1"
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "name": "scm_url",
                                        "type": "STRING",
                                        "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                        "description": "scm url"
                                      }
                                    ]
                                EOF
                            },
                    "table_2" =     {
                        "table_id" = "bq_table_2",
                        "schema"   = <<EOF
                                     [
                                      {
                                        "name": "scan_time2",
                                        "type": "STRING",
                                        "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                        "description": "scan time2"
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "name": "scan_duration2",
                                        "type": "STRING",
                                        "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                        "description": "scan duration2"
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "name": "scm_url2",
                                        "type": "STRING",
                                        "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                        "description": "scm url2"
                                      }
                                    ]
                                EOF
                      }
                }
            },
            "dataset2" = {
                "dataset_id"    = "bq_dataset_sentinel_test_2",
                "friendly_name" = "bq_dataset_sentinel_test_2",
                "table_schema" = {
                    "table_1" = {
                        "table_id"  = "bq_table_11",
                        "schema"    = <<EOF
                                      [
                                        {
                                          "name": "scan_time11",
                                          "type": "STRING",
                                          "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                          "description": "scan time11"
                                        },
                                        {
                                          "name": "scan_duration11",
                                          "type": "STRING",
                                          "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                          "description": "scan duration11"
                                        }
                                      ]
                                  EOF
                        },
                    "table_2" =     {
                        "table_id"  = "bq_table_22",
                        "schema"    = <<EOF
                                   [
                                    {
                                      "name": "scan_time22",
                                      "type": "STRING",
                                      "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                      "description": "scan time22"
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "name": "scan_duration22",
                                      "type": "STRING",
                                      "mode": "NULLABLE",
                                      "description": "scan duration22"
                                    }
                                  ]
                              EOF
                    }
                }
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a dataset separately from the tables.

Then use the generated dataset as a variable for each one of the tables.
[image]

You can find more info here:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_table

Comment: thanks for your response, but your solution did not resolve my issue,--- now im able to create multiple datasets with single table within each dataset,, but i want to create multiple tables within multiple datasets?

Comment: I mean, you can use the same variable but creating multiple resources, I mean you just need to replicate above code for table_2,table_3, with dataset_id = default.dataset_id

Comment: Im looking for the solution to automate multiple tables by creating single resource, by using for_each.

Comment: I mean you can use for_each, get it as a variable and then apply it in the table name for example. But if each table has different schema that won't be useful

Comment: yes each table had different schema

Comment: i just edited my question. at the last you can find the variable, which i was trying to flatten.